# Clear all elements under a certain div

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a news feed and I faced the following: 
I want to clear all items under the avatar, so there is no wrapped text or anything below.

This image shows the issue:
[image: http://imgur.com/RgReblc]

I want it to be like this (made it with Photoshop):
[image: http://imgur.com/1xP7rnn]

The code:

```css
.news .news-item .avatar {
  background-image: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35853519/zakzek.png");
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  background-size: cover;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 15px;
  display: block;
}
```

JSFiddle (see full screen for better view):
http://jsfiddle.net/shadeed9/6npjgt7y/8/

Thanks,

Comment: images doesn't work for me!

Comment: @PhilipG Try these please:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35853519/before.jpg and https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35853519/after.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is about dealing with float, then the `overflow:hidden;` rule is fine.

It shows element where float elements are standing as much inside than aside and earlier in the flow of the document.

http://jsfiddle.net/6npjgt7y/14/

```
.meta {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

It's about layout :)
So does trigger it as well : [`display:table`](http://jsfiddle.net/6npjgt7y/15/)/`inline-block`/`flex` and so does `float`.

Answer (score 1):

## **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6npjgt7y/10/)**

Add margin

```
.meta{
margin-right: 70px;
}
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6npjgt7y/11/)

or add padding

```
.meta{
padding-right: 70px;
}
```

or use transform

Answer (score 1):

Without altering the structure of the HTML, one way to achieve that is to add a margin on the meta content div with CSS. Like so:

```
div.meta { margin-right: 75px; }
```

That will move everything to the left. Just make the margin larger than your avatar image width and there won't be any wrapping.

Comment: Thanks! can we do the same thing by using altering the display property for the avatar? I tried to use inline-block but it doesn't work.

Comment: Well the margin property will offset the text from the edge of the page by however many pixels you want. The inline-block property will eliminate the wrapping but move the text under the avatar. So which property you use depends on how you want the content to display.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a table, put the avatar in one column and your other contents in second column, like this:

```
<div class="news" dir="rtl">
    <div class="news-item">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                    <div class="avatar"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="meta">
                        <h1>اطلاق تطبيق مسنجر بلاك بيري رسميًا إلى أندرويد وiOS7</h1>
                        <h2>لندن - "القدس" - كشف مصدر من شركة اتصالات اميركية أن الطلب المسبق على هاتف "أبل" الجديد "آيفون 5 سي" ليس "هائلاً" كما أن حجم المعروض منه ومن النسخة الأعلى سعراً جاء مخيباً للآمال. كشفت "أبل" الأسبوع الماضي النقاب عن أحدث طرازين...</h2>
                        <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35853519/apple.jpg" alt="Apple news" />
                        <div class="zakzeks-share">
                            <div class="number"><i class="flaticon-social19"></i>عدد الزقزقات 17</div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div> <!-- End of news -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving the avatar and the h2 element the property `display: inline-block` will do the trick, also set an `width` for the h2 element.

http://jsfiddle.net/6npjgt7y/9/

Comment: Thanks! what about the image and the text below it? how can we achieve the same result

Comment: In this case i would divide it in columns, like this: just but a wrapper around the avatar and set it to display: inline-block; and a certain height, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6npjgt7y/13/)